# Why aren't these 'xset' commands working from system() in C program on Raspberry Pi Raspbian?

Tags: c, bash, system, raspbian

I am working on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian and am trying to write a C program to turn the monitor off and on by using an ultrasonic sensor. I have been getting the behavior I want by using these commands manually from Bash:

```
#First, I export the display variable
export DISPLAY=:0.0

#To turn off the monitor:
sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o

#To turn on the monitor:
sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p
xset dpms force on
```

I want to execute these from within my C program by using the system() function, but am having issues with the xset commands.

```
system("echo $DISPLAY");
system("export DISPLAY=:0.0");
system("sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p && xset dpms force on");
```

Gives the output:

```
:0.0
Powering on HDMI with preferred settings
No protocol specified
xset: unable to open display ":0.0"
```

Even this:

```
system("xset -q");
```

Returns:

```
xset: unable to open display ":0.0"
```

I have seen several examples of people suggesting using the system() function to execute xset commands just like I'm trying to do and haven't seen anyone else mention having these exact same issues. It should also be noted that I am accessing the Pi through PuTTY. I'm not even sure if my problems are arising from a misunderstanding of xset, of the system() function, or something else. Any leads are appreciated!

## **Updated question**

One important thing pointed out is that `system` actually uses a new shell each time it is called, so even if setting `DISPLAY` variable had been productive, it would have no effect on the next invocation of `system'.

That helped me to understand how `system` actually works and to believe it should work the way I was using it. So I ran my C program directly on the Pi and not through SSH, and it actually works fine. For my current purposes, my problem is effectively solved because I don't actually need to work through SSH.

I do want to know why I was having the problems I had, and I think that is mainly connected to not understanding the X window system. I will read up on this more but if anyone has a hint to get me to the root of my particular problem, I would appreciate it. Currently I'm suspecting something to do with X forwarding...

Comment: Running commands with system is not the same as typing them in an interactive shell session.

Answer (score 1):

The different invocations of `system` will run different incarnations of your shell. They are independent of each other and in particular setting an environment variable makes no sense at all: the effect is over as soon as the `system` call ends.

From all that I can see your code makes not much sense to be implemented in C. You are better off with a shell script.

Comment: Ah OK I didn't realize each call of `system` is independent like that, thank you.


As far as using a shell script instead of C: I need to use the GPIO pins and am already familiar with using wiringPi libraries for that. What would be the advantages of using a shell script? Is it generally a bad idea for some reason to use `system`?